# Using two await inside the Blazor (async Task OnInitializedAsync) lifecycle doesn't work properly

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am using the following method in an operation.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
    await someOperation(); // this action is not perfomred
}
```

Any suggestion on this query

Comment: most likely answer is that the first call is throwing an error which you don't see because its lost in the Task. pop a try catch around each call and log any errors

Comment: No, i didn't face any errors in the first call, though it is not executed.

Comment: Client side Blazor or Server side Blazor?

Comment: Client-side, it works fine in server-side blazor

Comment: So, if you comment out the second line everything works?

Comment: If i comment the first line the second line works and commenting the second line first one works. Both is not executed in the same-time

Comment: Does "someOperation" use the forecasts returned by the first call?

Comment: Also, how are you checking whether the code has run?

Comment: I have just used the try catch and system.diagnostics to capture the catch exception

Comment: No there is no interaction between the second and first call "someOperation"

Comment: This is an extraordinary claim so you need extraordinary proof.

Comment: add a call ton `ConfigureAwait(false)` on both

Comment: and post the browser console log

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue in the past and I was able to fix it like:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json").ContinueWith(task => forecasts = task.Result); //Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes.


    await someOperation(); // his action can also be done using ContinueWith if needed
}
```

[ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) Doc:

Hope this helps.